# SQL for Classic ASP : How to insert record to tbl_order at the same time subtract qty from tbl_inventory and save back into Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

Currently I have the update code for insert record to tbl_order. Now that I implement the inventory section. I need the system can subtract qty from inventory once the order had been made.

I'm thinking about INSERT (Subtract (od_qty-tbl_inventory.inv_qty)) but I don't know how SQL statement gonna be in this case. So could you please help. Thank you

Below is my current update code for INSERT data to tbl_order.

```
<% 
dim od_total, cal_total, od_qty
cust_id = request.querystring("cust_id")
bill_id = request.querystring("bill_id")
pd_id = request.querystring("pd_id")
od_price = request.querystring("od_price")
od_qty = request.querystring("od_qty")
od_qty_unit = request.querystring("od_qty_unit")

date_current = date

        od_total = od_price * od_qty


Dim conn ' ADO connection
Dim rstSimple ' ADO recordset
Dim strDBPath ' path to our Access database (*.mdb) file
Dim bill_total

set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open(Server.Mappath("../database/tkp.mdb"))
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

' Next, the script inserts the form inputs retrieved from the querystring into the database table:
sql="INSERT INTO tbl_order (cust_id,bill_id,pd_id,od_price,od_qty,od_qty_unit,od_total)"
sql=sql & " VALUES "
sql=sql & "(" & cust_id & ","
sql=sql & "'" & bill_id & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & pd_id & "',"
sql=sql & "" & od_price & ","
sql=sql & "" & od_qty & ","
sql=sql & "'" & od_qty_unit & "',"
sql=sql & "" & od_total & ")"


'response.write sql
on error resume next
conn.Execute sql
if err<>0 then
Response.Write("No update permissions!") 'ae_name field is primary key so new record not inserted if name pre-exists in table
else
'Response.Write("<h3> Record added</h3>")
end if

rstSimple.Close
Set rstSimple = Nothing

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run an update query on your inventory table that subtracts the order quantity from the current inventory amount. Something like this:

```
sql = "UPDATE tbl_inventory SET inv_qty = inv_qty - " & od_qty & " WHERE pd_id = " & pd_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to solve your problem with transaction handling

```
conn.BeginTrans
'—Run Your Statements Here
conn.Execute sql1
conn.Execute sql2
conn.CommitTrans
```

Refer this for more info : http://classical-asp.blogspot.com/2010/08/transaction.html

EDIT : make sure inv_date column is a datetime column

```
sql1 = "UPDATE tbl_inventory SET inv_qty_act = inv_qty_act - " & od_qty & ", inv_date = now() WHERE pd_id = '" & pd_id & "'"
```

Comment: thank you. However I know where to put the code into. But my problem is I don't know  how to use the SQL statement to subtract in this case.